# Mainting state between tabs in react

Tags: reactjs

Maintaining state - Let's say you were doing something on one tab, when you move to the next and come back you should see the same state.
Any refernce for this or how to achive this i am new to react

Comment: Ideally, you should show your effort because no single solution is a perfect solution in software engineering. Your effort will let us know where you are sstuck so we can help you. Try creating an example on codesandbox and post the link so we can refer to something.

Comment: Please add some code, of what you have now or what you've attempted to do. It very much depends on how you render the tabs and what library do you use.

Answer (score 0):

What you want here is a method to persist your data onto your browser, so you can dehydrate them whenever the user visits your page on different tabs.

[Here](https://www.joshwcomeau.com/react/persisting-react-state-in-localstorage/) you have an awesome step-by-step guide.

Essentially, the idea behind it, is you save your state data into your localStorage, so you can then retrieve them back whenever you need it